# With HTML5 drag and drop, how can I change the drag image when it's over the drop zone?

Tags: image, html, drag-and-drop

So here's what I want to do. I would like to be able to drag an element, and have it dynamically change it's default drag image to a different image when it's over the drop zone.

Comment: Please ask one question per question, and use a descriptive title (eg, "how do I change the drag image in HTML5 when mousing over the drop zone?")

Comment: sorry about that, I edited to only include one question.

Comment: thanks - it causes problems when people ask more than one question in a question, because then if someone answers only half of it, and another person answers the other half, you can't accept both, or you might end up with a question that looks answered in the index but really is only half answered, etc. Feel free to open another question at the same time with your other question.

Comment: No problem, thanks a lot! Looks like this question is a tough one.

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately I'm not much the HTML type, so I can't answer it myself :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are able to set the drag image using `dataTransfer.setDragImage` method. It exists in the event objects of all of the drag events, including the `dragover` event.

Some basic code would be:

```
dropElem.ondragover = function(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    }
    var dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
    dragIcon.src = 'image.png';
    dragIcon.width = 100;
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: Has anyone ever successfully applied this? Setting the drag image after the `dragstart` event does not work for me, with any browser.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212718/how-to-change-icon-during-dragover-dragenter-html-5-drag-and-drop) we CANNOT change this due to security reasons.