# How to change icon during dragover/dragenter HTML 5 Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to change DnD's (drag and drop) icon during dragover or dragenter? Is it even possible?

I am able to change the icon during dragstart if the source of the drop is inside the html page (for example drag a div in an other div). Here is my code, I am working with angular, I have set a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nRxBiqzPq58dR1jto2ZR?p=preview).

```
app.directive('drag', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.attr('draggable', true);
      element.css('cursor', 'move');

      element.bind('dragstart', function(event) {
        console.log('dragstart');
        console.log(event.dataTransfer);
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/google.jpg";
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

But it doesn't work to change the icon if the source is a file for example or an url, here is the code. I am trying to change the icon during dragover or dragenter.

```
element.bind('dragenter', function(event) {
  console.log('dragenter');
  event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/google.jpg";
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
});

element.bind('dragover', function(event) {

  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  console.log('dragover');

  element.addClass('dragged');

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/google.jpg";
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the specification, you cannot use **setDragImage** on events other than drag start. See here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#dom-datatransfer-setdragimage

> The setDragImage(element, x, y) method must run the following steps:
>
> 1. If the DataTransfer object is no longer associated with a drag data
>      store, return. Nothing happens.
> 2. If the drag data store's mode **is not the read/write mode**, return.
>      Nothing happens.
> 3. If element is an img element, then set the drag data store bitmap to
>      the element's image (at its intrinsic size); otherwise, set the drag
>      data store bitmap to an image generated from the given element (the
>      exact mechanism for doing so is not currently specified).
> 4. Set the drag data store hot spot coordinate to the given x, y
>      coordinate.

And here, you can see that the drag data store is in read/write mode only on dragstart: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#concept-dnd-rw

> Read/write mode For the dragstart event. New data can be added to the
>   drag data store.

These are modes are there for security reasons, there are things you can do on the different stages of a drag and drop.

Comment: @PeterMoore I don't think there is one, this is per design.

Comment: There's always a workaround. :) I guess in this case the only workaround is implementing D&D from scratch.

Comment: Well that sucks :/

Comment: An alternate option is to `setDragImage(new Image(), 9999, 0)` and then implement a custom overlay that tracks with the mouse.  I do something like that for [JS File Explorer](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/js-fileexplorer).  It's not quite implementing D&D from scratch because it still has the benefit of cross-window/tab D&D with dragstart/enter/over/etc. whereas a mousedown/mousemove style solution would only work in the current window/tab.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good to know this